# Clearly identify beginner or experienced questions?

Tags: discussion

This started out as, "Can I ask for a proofreader to an almost-finished project?", but as I read a bunch of other meta questions, I think the answer to that is yes, if I frame it as a specific concept being clarified with my project as the example.

Which brings me to my new point: The main reason I wasn't sure about it was because of all the n00b/get-me-started/don't-understand-the-basics type of questions that seem to grow like weeds.  I don't want to discourage genuine newbies needing a jump-start, but I think that maybe we should have some kind of separation between Flashlight 101 and Mixed-Signal 241 so that it's easier to find the latter.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

The distinction exists, but I don't think that an explicit separation would be helpful. It might have adverse effects like implying that lower standards (in style, not in technical content) would be applied, which many users would disagree about.